# How do I pass a html value into an AngularJS method?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to pass a value from a html element angularJS method bound to the $scope.

The code is...

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="miniC">

      <input name="someitem" ng-blur="CalculateTotals(this)"/>

</div>

function miniC($scope){


    $scope.myAccounts =  new Array();

    $scope.CalculateTotals = function(amt){

        console.log(amt);

    }


}
```

[codepane link](http://cdpn.io/qshtK)

But I cannot seem to extract the value from the element. I do not want to bind in this case as I am trying some things out and this was one of the approaches I had....

Answer (score 1):

Angular expressions are all properties of the scope they are evaluated on, so `this` will just be the current scope.

With this in mind, you **have** to make this available on the scope. The simplest way is to use `ng-model="someValue"`, then use `ng-blur="CalculateTotals(someValue)"`.

However I also note in your question you explicitly don't want to bind, and this does add some overheads if you don't use anything else, so you would have to create a custom directive instead.

Comment: Ah cool mate I see right that makes sense yeah I guess I can just put it anywhere on the model, I was thinking laterally like that. I'll answer as correct when I can...

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to turn an input into a model's representation with `ng-model` directive, allowing to access its value directly. But if, for some reasons, you don't want to do this, you still can access this element - via `target` property of `$event` variable exposed by [**ngBlur**](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBlur) directive. For example:

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="miniC">
    <input name="someitem" ng-blur="AddToTotal($event.target)" />
    <button type="button" ng-click="Reset()">Reset</button>
    <br />
    <span>Totals: {{ CalculateTotals() }}</span>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
function miniC($scope) {
    $scope.myAccounts = [];

    $scope.Reset = function() {
        this.myAccounts.length = 0;
    }

    $scope.CalculateTotals = function() {
        return this.myAccounts.reduce(function(sum, el) {
            return sum + el;
        }, 0);
    };

    $scope.AddToTotal = function(inp) {
        var value = inp.value;
        this.myAccounts.push(+value);
    };
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2Tkf3/). It works somewhat funny, as a new value is added each time focus is moved out of that input.

Answer (score 0):

Append `ng-model="testVal"` to your input field and `console.log($scope.testVal);` to log your value.